# Multiple Threads Starting Up Spontaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a very bizarre situation. It appears that, when I load a webpage to my browser,
multiple threads (at least 2) are starting up. The app loads and runs fine on a
Windows XP box, but when I try to run it on my Windows 8 laptop it would seem that
more than one startup event is taking place and causing all kinds of collisions. This
is happening with both Firefox and IE.

To verify this behaviour, I placed a static int within a class, checked it to see if its
value is greater than zero, throw an exception if it is, then increment the int.

Of course, the exception is thrown.

What's very weird about this is that there is no multi-threading/multi-tasking involved
within my app.

When I "touch" the DLL for the webpage (rebuild it), it renders the webpage properly,
but the source for the webpage ("right click" > "View Page Source") has the source
for the unhandled exception webpage, with the message for the exception that my code
throws when the thread count is greater than zero.

I've tried creating a new project, then linking the code to it (Add Item ... Ad As Link),
then building it. It didn't do any good.

The Win XP system has IIS 6 with .NET 4.0, and the Win 8 laptop has IIS 7 with .NET 4.0.

Language is C#.

The truth is that I'm pretty much clueless about IIS.

I hope someone smarter than I am (which isn't saying much) has an idea as to what
is going on.

Comment: I'm just guessing that you might have missed enabling 32 bit application in IIS7 on your Windows 8 64-bit. Your application would need that if -according to you- it was running over IIS6 that is probably installed on a 32-bit Windows XP: Check [here](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx)

Comment: What's the actual question? No question mark found.

Comment: @yazanpro - I've enabled 32-bit application on the app pools, and there was no effect. As I mentioned in my post, I recreated the project on the Win 8 laptop, then built it, so wouldn't it have built the DLL for 64-bit?

Comment: @usr - the question is: Why are there multiple threads starting up and running a single-thread app when I load the webpage? More importantly: How do I get it to stop doing that?

Comment: Why is your code sensitive to number of threads? After startup, you'll get at least one thread per request - quite likely at the same time.

Comment: @John Saunders - I should only be getting one thread per Page_Init. For reasons that are not clear to me, the Page_Init handler is being called by multiple threads of execution. I've tried killing all threads after the first one (Thread.Abort), but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that, when I load a webpage to my browser, multiple threads (at least 2) are starting up

Maybe onetime initializations. I doubt that *every request* causes an *additional* two threads to stay around.

> it would seem that more than one startup event is taking place

That's normal This event fires for each instance of `HttpApplication` being created. This is basically a design error in ASP.NET. They thought that pooling `HttpApplication` instances and assigning one of them for each request was a good idea. It would have been better to have a singleton per AppDomain. Write this yourself. Like that:

```
class MyGlobalAppState { ... }
static Lazy<MyGlobalAppState> state = new Lazy<...>(StateFactory);
```

Be aware, that `Lazy<T>` stores any exception and just rethrows it. This causes your app to be permanently broken in case `StateFactory` throws. It will never recover without pool restart. This is a design error in `Lazy<T>`. Find a way to deal with that.

> but the source for the webpage ("right click" > "View Page Source") has the source for the unhandled exception webpage

Some browsers re-GET the page to view the source. This can be annoying or handy.

Comment: I should've mentioned that this is a webforms app. Would statefactory be applicable here? If so, how would I use it with the Page instance, and the Page_Init and Page_Load handlers?

Comment: I don't see how those are connected with this idea. I understand you want to have some global init-once data. That's probably what you were using App_Start for.

Comment: I believe that we have a misunderstanding here. I'm not using App_Start and there is no global data involved. When I load the .aspx page (webform) into the browser, my code is being executed more than once, apparently on more than one thread, causing havoc. I need to stop this behavior. I'm guessing it has something to do with IIS and the way I have it configured - as I mentioned before: I'm pretty much clueless about IIS. I'm open to the possibility that I could be making a false assumption in that regard, and that this is being caused by something else entirely.

Comment: If there are multiple concurrent requests and they do not share state, why would that cause havoc? And what do you mean by "it would seem that more than one startup event is taking place"? It is really hard helping you if you speak in mysteries.

Comment: That's the problem: My app does not involve multiple concurrent requests - it is all a single-thread (at this time). There are update panels involved, but I don't think that this is an issue, as the problem is manifesting itself at Page_Init. (However, I could be wrong about this. If anyone sees something that I don't, then please set me straight.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? ASP.NET apps are never single threaded. Why do you think they might be? Concurrent HTTP requests are processed concurrently. Probably, your page just causes another request to be run. Use Fiddler to see what it is. And again, how does that exactly cause trouble?

Comment: It's a problem because the code that is being executed is intended to be executed in one thread, and one thread only. On the Win XP box, it is being executed as it should and everything is working fine. On the Win 8 system, the Page_Init handler is being called more than once (apparently by another thread) for reasons that I do not understand. (I am doing nothing to start another thread.) I don't believe that webforms are supposed to do that. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Yes, a single HTTP request runs single-threadedly. There is probably another HTTP request coming in that you do not expect. Again: find out what it is. I didn't suggest to use Fiddler without reason. If you don't find a concurrent request look at the call stack to see who is calling this function. Why would ASP.NET call the same function on the same page multiple times, and further more on multiple threads? That theory is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is causing this behavior but as others suggested try to use Fiddler or any other http tracing tool to see what requests are sent.

Also, Win XP should be running IIS5.x while Win8 should be running IIS8.

By default IIS8 AppPool should be running with the integrated pipeline, which may behave differently. I would try changing the AppPool to use the Classic pipeline to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hi all;

I've managed to get Fiddler to work.

After "touching" the DLL, I opened my .aspx page, and got the following
two entries:

Comment: # Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
3155 500 HTTP localhost /CtrlI/Ctrl12.aspx 5,466 private text/html; charset=utf-8 firefox:4568   

REQUEST HEADER
GET /Ctrl/Ctrl12.aspx HTTP/1.1
RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

# Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
3156 200 HTTP localhost /Ctrl/Ctrl12.aspx 15,534 private text/html; charset=utf-8 firefox:4568   
REQUEST HEADER
GET /Ctrl/Ctrl12.aspx HTTP/1.1
RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: The page rendered as it should, in spite of the 500 Internal Server Error
in the first response.

I then attempted a postback, and got another 500 Internal Server Error:

Comment: # Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
3177 500 HTTP localhost /Ctrl/Ctrl12.aspx 5,466 private text/html; charset=utf-8 firefox:4568   

REQUEST HEADER
GET /Ctrl/Ctrl12.aspx HTTP/1.1
RESPONSE HEADER
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very useful.

Is there something else that I should examine within Fiddler?

Thanks!

Comment: Right it does not provide much information. Did you try to change the AppPool Pipeline Mode to Classic?

Comment: @Julian Jacobs - tried that - no good. For a moment, I thought it might be the "magic button" that I've been looking for. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Check out this thread as well. http://forums.asp.net/t/1568046.aspx?Page_init+called+twice